# Odd 'expected ;' error that I can't find

Tags: javascript, html, css, syntax

I posted on here before about a completely different issue, but now my clock (which when stepping through, seems to work perfectly fine) returns a '; expected' error, about every 500 milliseconds I would guess based on my variable "t". Then it stops after 8-12 iterations. Says the error is in the 3rd line, 1st column of the html file.

```js
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    var t = setInterval(startTime(), 500);
 return h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};
    return i;
}
```

```css
.headtitle {
 color:red;
 font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: center;
 border: 5px solid #00f;
 padding: 10px;
}
.subtitle{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: center;
 font-size: 1.25rem
}
a.firstlink{
 word-spacing: 30px;
}
a:visited{
 color:lightblue
}
body{
 background-image: url("http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/a942qcqwrcmveiq37zli.png");
 background-repeat:repeat;
 color: white;
}
.list{
 display: inline;
}
.list li{
 display: inline;
 padding-left: 1.5rem;
}
.button{
 float:right;
 border: 1px solid #f00;
 padding: 5px
}
.button:active{
 position: relative;
 top: 2px;
 left: 2px;
}
.JavascriptButton{
 float:right;
}
.clickText{
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Website task.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="new 1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function openFunction()
   {
    window.open('Website Task.html', '_blank');
   }
   function showTime()
   {
    document.getElementById("currentTime").innerHTML = "The time is now " + startTime();
    t = setInterval(startTime(), 500);
   }
  </script>
  <title>Javascript page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="header">
   <h1 class="headtitle">Javascript demo page</h1>
   <p class="subtitle">This page is for demonstrating functions in Javascript in particular, as well as jQuery.</p>
   <p id="currentTime"></p>
   <button id="timeButton" onclick="showTime()" onclick="removeElement('header','timeButton');">Click here to show the time</button>
   <p></p>
   <a class="clickText" onclick="openFunction()">Click this text to return to the previous page in a new window</a>
   <button class="JavascriptButton" onclick="window.location='Website Task.html';">Previous page</button>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some things to note... You're calling `setInterval` by calling the callback function immediately instead of passing it. The `startTime()` function calls itself recursively. Once you fix the `setInterval` call, that's going to increase the number of intervals running exponentially.

Comment: The only reason I added that part is because the setInteral function didn't seem to be working in the first place. Removing that does seem to fix the errors, actually, but the clock is still frozen.

Comment: I guess `var t = setInterval(startTime(), 500);` will break code. Not for semicolon, but an infinite recursion with interval

Comment: I got a `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` when running the time.

Comment: @Zeratops Thats because of infinite recursion.

Comment: @JackRaiden: That's why. You shouldn't be calling the `startTime` function when you pass it., and you definitely shouldn't have it start more intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `startTime` and `showTime` for only one `setInterval`.

As well you may just hand over the function to the `setInteval` without calling it.

```
var t = setInterval(startTime, 500);
//                          ^^^ no parenthesis
```

```js
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);       
    document.getElementById("currentTime").innerHTML = "The time is now " + h + ":" + m + ":" + s; // add this here        
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};
    return i;
}
```

```css
.headtitle {
 color:red;
 font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: center;
 border: 5px solid #00f;
 padding: 10px;
}
.subtitle{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: center;
 font-size: 1.25rem
}
a.firstlink{
 word-spacing: 30px;
}
a:visited{
 color:lightblue
}
body{
 background-image: url("http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/a942qcqwrcmveiq37zli.png");
 background-repeat:repeat;
 color: white;
}
.list{
 display: inline;
}
.list li{
 display: inline;
 padding-left: 1.5rem;
}
.button{
 float:right;
 border: 1px solid #f00;
 padding: 5px
}
.button:active{
 position: relative;
 top: 2px;
 left: 2px;
}
.JavascriptButton{
 float:right;
}
.clickText{
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Website task.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="new 1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function openFunction()
   {
    window.open('Website Task.html', '_blank');
   }
   function showTime()
   {
    var t = setInterval(startTime, 500);
    startTime();
   }
  </script>
  <title>Javascript page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="header">
   <h1 class="headtitle">Javascript demo page</h1>
   <p class="subtitle">This page is for demonstrating functions in Javascript in particular, as well as jQuery.</p>
   <p id="currentTime"></p>
   <button id="timeButton" onclick="showTime()" onclick="removeElement('header','timeButton');">Click here to show the time</button>
   <p></p>
   <a class="clickText" onclick="openFunction()">Click this text to return to the previous page in a new window</a>
   <button class="JavascriptButton" onclick="window.location='Website Task.html';">Previous page</button>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a surplus ; after your if statement. Make it:

```
function checkTime(i) {
if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i}
return i;
}
```

Also the error you are experiencing is that the maximum call stack size has been exceeded. This is because your function setTime() is calling itself

Comment: That doesn't cause an error. It's just a JavaScript "empty statement"

Comment: Well, the semicolon should be really within the block.

Comment: Doesn't solve anything, it seems. Clock still frozen and errors still appearing.

Comment: @LittleSanti: It really doesn't matter if that semicolon is in, out or absent. It won't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is when you do `setInterval(startTime(), 500);`, it is actually `setInterval("04:43:00", 500);`. `setInterval` expects first argument as function.

#### Sample

```js
function startTime(){
  return new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
}

setTimeout(startTime(), 500)
```